# Exception at line 1 of java class

Tags: java, exception

I have a strange exception:

```
11:35:16,822 ERROR [jsp:154] java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mine.portal.security.portlet.web.MyRenderRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(MyRenderRequestWrapper.java:16)
    at org.mine.portal.security.portlet.web.MyRenderRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(MyRenderRequestWrapper.java:1)
```

it is very strange because for it pass on the line 1, and the other line of the exception is this:

```
1.  package org.mine.portal.security.portlet.web;
2.  
3.  import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
4.  import javax.portlet.filter.RenderRequestWrapper;
5.  
6.  import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
7.  import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
8.  
9.  public class MyRequestWrapper extends RenderRequestWrapper {
10. 
11.     public PortalRenderRequestWrapper(RenderRequest request) {
12.         super(request);
13.     }
14.     
15.     @Override
16.     public Authentication getUserPrincipal() {
17.         return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
18.     }
```

Someone have an idea of what it can be?

Comment: post the line `MyRenderRequestWrapper.java:16`

Comment: I think it's best if you print out the code from the top of your class till line 16 which seems to be the problem.

Comment: the line i've written is the line 16

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from this part `[jsp:154]` it came from JSP which you are probably somehow rendering with your wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Anything reporting an error on line 1 usually is because the error is elsewhere but it cannot accurately be reported.  This is frequently because the error is outside *your* code so there is no source line to convert back to.

How does line 16 look?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the fact that the user is not logged in:

**getUserPrincipal**

*public java.security.Principal* **getUserPrincipal()**

Returns a java.security.Principal object containing the name of the current authenticated user. If the user has not been authenticated, the method returns null.

**Returns:**
*a java.security.Principal* containing the name of the user making this request; null if the user has not been authenticated

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal()

Comment: It is possible you have configured sessions to be invalidated when you re-deploy at which point you will see similar behavior.

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but it might be worth a look. My IDE allows me to preserve or invalidate sessions across redeployments. I don't assume it discriminates between portlets or the entire application.

Comment: mmm no is some other...because now i put a System.out in the method redeployed and it throws a NoClassDefFoundError...........

Answer (score 0):

When you use generics or have a co-variant return type (i suspect the latter here) the compiler generates an additional method to support backward compatibility and inheritance.

At the JVM level the return type is part of the method signature (even if it isn't in Java)

Say you have this code

```
public class A {
    public Number method() { return 1L; }
}

public class B extends A {
    public Double method() { return 2.0; }
}
```

In the JVM, `Number method()` is not overrideen by `Double method()` as the signatures are different so the javac compiler adds a method in byte code like

```
public class B extends A {
    public transient Number method() { return (Number)<Double>method(); } // calls the first method
    public Double method() { return 2.0; }
}
```

This generated method has no source and is notionally placed at line 1 in your source file. (I am not sure why the method has the same modifier as a transient field would have)